# Azure DW + DQS + MDS Architectures

Tags: sql-server, azure, master-data-services, data-quality-services

What is a typical architecture if I want to use MDS and DQS for my Azure environment. I've been trying to search for some references and couldn't find a clear solution.

Currently what I only know if I want to use DQS and MDS for my Azure DW is that I have to get a VM which has MDS. Then does that mean when I load data it has to pass thru that DQS/MDS DB in the VM before loading to Azure DW?

Greatly appreciate if someone would be able to explain and apologies if my question is a bit confusing.

Comment: This should probably be moved to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/